# Post Insights metrics missing in meta api documentation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, documentation

I'm trying to find all metrics that are available for post insights but I can't find it in Meta's API documentation.
I only found this endpoint documentation that does not include metrics
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/insights/

[Page insights documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/insights#page-posts) does include metrics but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not sure if they have an extra list for that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/insights#page-post-engagement and the following two are for individual page posts already. What more are you expecting to find?

Comment: What are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: I would also suggest upgrading the API version, v.15 is over one year old.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know if you want Page Posts or User Posts, because the permissions that you need and the info that you can get from each is different.

You can get basic info and public metrics of both Page Posts / User Posts (such as text, author, comments, likes...) as explained here: [Post fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v18.0/post#fields).

As for Insights, all the metrics available for Page Posts are these: [Page Insights > Page Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v18.0/insights#page-posts). You cannot get insights for User Posts; see [Post edges](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v18.0/post#edges).